# Spring MVC Requests with no mapping are going to a controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I encountered a strange issue that I cannot find any documentation explaining. I have a controller with the URL mapping /profiles.  I started accidentally sending in requests /profile.  Normally in my experience, this would result in a 404 as I have no controllers mapped to /profile but instead I started getting null pointers in my /invitations controller and sure enough if I put a breakpoint in the invitation controllers base GetMapping method it was getting hit.

The invitation controller is not referenced in any of my config classes nor is mapped with any wild cards that would allow /profile to go it.  What's more any improper URLs even at lower levels such as /(any-controller}/{id}/something-wrong will go to it.  Is there some kind of default controller setting in spring I am missing?

Comment: Please add some logging and code, configuration to your question. Also are you using Spring Boot or plain Spring?

Comment: It is not spring boot.  What logging are you specifically looking for in the logs and configs as I will have to generify it?  For logs, I have it heavily tuned because Spring Session is very verbose.  I assume you mean springs logs as this clearly happens above my code. I have the following configs/WebApplicationInitializers: GlobalWebApplicationInitializer, GlobalWebMVCRootConfig, GlobalSpringSecurityConfig, GlobalSpringSessionConfig,  and GlobalMethodSecurityConfig